# NuGet does not recognize $(SolutionDir) variable at solution root folder

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I have been using a central packages folder for a quite time now (using `%AppData%/NuGet/NuGet.config`), but for some requirements I need to use solution-level packages repository now for a certain solution.

For this I created this NuGet.config and placed it at the solution root.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <packageRestore>
    <!-- Allow NuGet to download missing packages -->
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />

    <!-- Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio -->
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>

  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="$(Solutiondir)\Packages" />
  </config>

  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>

</configuration>
```

However, the funny thing is that a folder named `$(Solutiondir)` is created which contains the `Packages` folder where the packages are stored.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by NuGet. The path is either a full directory path or a path relative to the NuGet.Config file itself.

You can get the desired behaviour by having a NuGet.Config file for each solution either in its .nuget directory or the solution directory. Then specify the directory relative to the NuGet.Config file.

Comment: Oh, I did not realize it. When I just read that the default path is "$(SolutionDir)\Packages" in this page: http://docs.nuget.org/consume/NuGet-Config-Settings, I thought to myself why not to use it.

It is actually stated that it can be either absolute path or relative to the solution. Thanks.